# Asus 1015cx netbook won't boot in 12.04 after installing additional drivers

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers

I have an Asus 1015cx netbook with Atom dual core, 1GB RAM. I installed Ubuntu 12.04  with WUBI inside Windows 7 and everything was okay.

But when I installed additional drivers of **Broadcom** and **Cedar Trail**, the netbook does not boot after restart. There appears a blank screen and cursor keeps blinking. The same problem happened with Xubuntu 12.04.

Please suggest.

Comment: what happen when you use recovery mode (during start up)?

Comment: it runs some commands..and then the same blank screen.. No booting

Comment: what wast the last message? Did recovery shows any error message? Do  you have any graphics card?

Comment: sorry i couldn't find any error when i wrote this..all i got after running the recovery mode is a blank screen..now as u asked i again tried to enter recovery mode, but it won't let me do.. 
this netbook has Intel® Atom™ N2600 (Dual Core; 1.6GHz)
Processor, no  separate graphics card

Comment: it's difficult to recover "inside windows"  installed system. Also you can not access root shell. So recommend you to backup your system and go for fresh install.

Comment: ok..thanks for your reply shantanu. i'll try that. Bt i'm planning not to update those drivers, otherwise this problem may happen again.. 
i want to know if somebody on this forum had this trouble and how they tackled..